# Should I store ingredients as seperate table or as lists

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with recipes. I could make two separate table; one for the recipe (title and instructions), and another for ingredients (ingredient, how much of it..etc) with a reference to a specific recipe. This way i would have a bunch of ingredients pointing to a specific recipe.

- Table Recipe

  - id = 0
  - title = 'Chocolate Cake'
  - instructions = 'Put it in the oven'
- Table Ingredients

  - id = 0
  - ingredient = 'flour'
  - amount = '2'
  - measurement = 'cups'
  - recipe_reference = 0

    ---
  - id = 1
  - ingredient = 'oil'
  - amount = '3'
  - measurement = 'teaspoon'
  - recipe_reference = 0

Or I could make 1 database and store all the ingredient info as a list of strings

- Table Recipe

  - title = 'Chocolate Cake'
  - instruction = 'Put it in the oven'
  - ingredients = 'flour|oil'
  - amounts = '2|3'
  - measurements = 'cups|teaspoon'

I figured the first way is clearer but uses a new table for every ingredient while the second way uses one table per recipe which will make my database much smaller and faster to query as its smaller and i don't need to make any unnecessary joins.
Any idea which way is better in the long run?

Comment: The first pattern is the normative relational pattern. Consider a future use case, for example, find all recipe with "oil" as an ingredient. Or if you needed to enforce a foreign key constraint... you would find the second pattern to be unsuitable.  Bill Karwin has written an excellent book which has a chapter that covers the topic of "storing lists" in a column. "SQL Antipatterns: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming" available from Amazon and other fine booksellers. https://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356557/  (See Chapter 2. Jaywalking)

Comment: You would have 3 tables: recipes, ingredients... and a third table, recipe_ingredient, which would record how much of each ingredient belongs in each recipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, avoid creating data that stores multiple values in a single column. See my answer to [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

SQL is really based on an assumption that you store one irreducible value in each column. Things get really difficult and inefficient when you need to query sub-elements out of a single column.

So if you **always** fetch the full list of ingredients and then read through the list in your application, you may use a pipe-delimited list as you show in your second example.

But if you *ever* plan on using SQL expressions to work on individual elements of the list, do yourself a favor and break it out into separate rows in a child table.

Comment: doesn't joins take longer then querying one table? Like if i have millions of ingredients rows and I want a specific recipe so the query would have to go through all of the ingredient rows and pick out the ones whos ref_id match my recipe. But if i do it the second way; it already know which ingredients once it has recipe id

Comment: @eliezerperlowitz, if you define indexes correctly, a join shouldn't be a hard thing for the RDBMS. But if you choose the denormalized design, queries like "all recipes that contain cardamom" will be impossible to optimize, requiring a very expensive full table scan. It's better to compromise on the *slight* cost of a join, to make it possible to optimize different types of queries.

Comment: @eliezerperlowitz, Another way of thinking about it: Denormalization is indeed used sometimes to avoid the join, but only if you are totally certain you will not need to do the complementary kinds of queries that will be made much more expensive by the denormalization. **Every** kind of optimization helps one type of query at the expense of some other types of queries. You can't make blanket rules like "I never want to do joins" because which optimization design you choose depends on the queries you need to be efficient.

Comment: I'm still confused a little. Having, lets say, only 50,000 recipes would mean millions of ingredient rows. Every time querying for 1 recipe; you would have to go through millions of ingredients to find which ones have the ref_id of the recipe to put together the simple recipe, while the 2nd way would automatically give you the ingredients since their in the recipe table. Isn't that more then a slight cost?

Comment: @eliezerperlowitz, You would incur a table-scan like you describe if you did not create an appropriate index in the ingredients table. You should create an index to help. Then it will quickly find the matching rows—*without* scanning the whole ingredients table. Creating the right indexes to support the queries you run is absolutely a necessary part of optimizing a relational database.

Answer (score 1):

Two is better, but I would do three tables. `recipes`, `ingredients`, and `recipe_ingredients`. The difference in query time for either of your ideas and mine will be unnoticeable. The 3 table setup will store less data because instead of storing "flour" 10,000 times, you will have it in the DB once and the ID (an integer) will be used in the linking table.